# Adding setInterval inside a method Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that I can get to out numbers 0 - 9:

```
var countup = {
    i: 0,
    startCount: function () {
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}

countup.startCount();
```

now I need to be able to get it to output the numbers at 1 second intervals, I have tried this code below that is just giving me an undefined output:

```
var countup = {
    i: 0,
    startCount: function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                console.log(i);
            }
        }, 1000)
    }
}
countup.startCount();
```

Does anyone have have any ideas how I can edit the code above to give the desired output of numbers 0 - 9 at one second intervals?

Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jpsefv63/

Comment: I don't think that's a close duplicate at all (yes they've also got conflicting `i` variables but the question is about the setInterval issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `let` for declaring `i` and use `setTimeout` since you have to call  console.log counter only ten times not forever..

```js
var countup = {
  startCount: function () {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(i);
       }, i*1000)
     }
   }
}
countup.startCount();
```

Comment: Thanks very much that works!

Answer (score 4):

> See the second and third snippets for better answers.

You can do it like this, using `setInterval` and `clearInterval` when the count reaches 10. Also, to access the variable `i` in your countup object, you can do it with `this.i`:

```js
const countup = {
    i: 0,
    startCount: function() {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(this.i);
            if (++this.i === 10) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
         }, 1000);
    }
}

countup.startCount();
```

**As mentionned by @Hit-or-miss**, `this` should not be used in a static object.
Here is a better way to do it using the `prototype`.

This allows you to have multiple counters that don't share their internal count.

```js
function Countup() {
  this.i = 0;
}

Countup.prototype = {
    constructor: Countup, // Good practice

    startCount: function() {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(this.i);
            if (++this.i === 10) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
};

const counter1 = new Countup();
const counter2 = new Countup();

counter1.startCount();
counter2.startCount();
```

Or, using **JavaScript classes**:

> The arrow functions and classes are supported only in modern browsers.

```js
class Countup {
    constructor() {
        this.i = 0;
    }

    startCount() {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(this.i);
            if (++this.i === 10) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
};

const counter1 = new Countup();
const counter2 = new Countup();

counter1.startCount();
counter2.startCount();
```

Comment: You should not use the "this" context in the static objects.

Comment: You are totally right, I added your warning to my answer

Comment: Thanks very they all work! :)